# How To Read String from Arduino when am selecting no line ending at arduino serial moniter

Tags: arduino, embedded

[image]How To Read String from Arduino when am selecting no line ending at arduino serial monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use the line ending (CR+LF) to identify end of user input. In your case it is not clear what will be the end of line terminator. Assuming '.' (period) than you should consume characters from the Serial until you reach the line terminator.
Here's an example code:

```
#define EOL_TERMINATOR '.'

int inByte = 0;         // incoming serial byte
String cmdLine;

void setup()
{
  // start serial port at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  cmdLine = "";
}

void loop()
{
  // if we get a valid byte, read analog ins:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // get incoming byte:
    inByte = Serial.read();
    if (inByte != EOL_TERMINATOR)
      cmdLine.concat(inByte);
    else {
      userCommand(cmdLine);
      cmdLine = ""; //reset cmdLine for next command
    }
  }
}

void userCommand(String cmd) {
  Serial.println("User command '"+cmd+"'");
}
```

Comment: sure, just replace the '.' with your ASCII number  `#define EOL_TERMINATOR 64`